# post method not allowed in HitCountDetailView

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

Adding a Comment Form to Django Blog Post: Encountering following error

> Method Not Allowed (POST)
> this is my view

```
class  BlogDetailView(HitCountDetailView):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post']
    model = BlogModel
    context_object_name = 'blog_detail'
    template_name = 'main/single.html'
    count_hit = True
    

    # for show all post in the sidebar
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        blog = self.get_object()  # Get the current blog post
        
        # Get the comments related to the current blog post
        comments = CommentModel.objects.filter(blog=blog,active = True)
        context['comments'] = comments
        context['blogposts'] = BlogModel.objects.filter(status = 'p')[:3]  # Get blog posts for the sidebar

        # Pass the comment form to the context
        context['comment_form'] = CommentForm()
        return context

     
        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            blog_post = self.get_object()
            comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)

            if comment_form.is_valid():
                comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
                comment.blog = blog_post
                comment.save()
                return redirect('app:mag_detail',  slug=blog_post.slug) 

            context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['comment_form'] = comment_form
            return self.render_to_response(context)
```

and this is template

```
 <h1>comment </h1>
                <form method="post" action="{% url 'app:mag_detail' slug=mag_detail.slug %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ comment_form.as_p }}
                    <button type="submit">Submit Comment</button>
                </form>
```

how can I solve that?
thanks

I'm currently working on integrating a comment form into my Django blog post using a class-based view. My goal is to allow users to submit comments on each blog post. While the form is displayed correctly on the template, I'm facing a "Method Not Allowed (POST)" error when attempting to submit the form.